# Order of evaluation with exception

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is in below expression if exception if thrown on the rhs of assignment ie: 
bad_alloc will **linesArg** already be decremented?:

```
try{    
  buffer[--linesArg] = new char[rows];
}catch(std::bad_alloc& ba){

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment is not a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). Therefore, the order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified. The compiler may pick any order. It may even pick a different order each time you compile.

You should extract the `--linesArg` expression to its own statement to get well-defined behaviour.

Comment: Formally, the order is **unspecified**, not **undefined**. Informally, yes, it's undefined, but "undefined" has a particular meaning in the standard that doesn't apply here. It's generally better to stick to the formal term, to avoid confusion (and to placate nitpicking language lawyers).

Answer (score 3):

No, the [Order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) of the operands is unspecified.

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.
>
> There are several exceptions to this rule (e.g. for the &&, ||, and , operators) which are noted below.
>
> Otherwise, there is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to f3 may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time.

```
buffer[--linesArg] = new char[rows];
```

is parsed as

```
operator=(operator[](buffer, --linesArg), new char[rows]);
```

The arguments will be evaluated before the function invoked (i.e. `buffer` and `--linesArg` will be evaluated before `operator[]` called, `operator[]()` and `new char[rows]` will be evaluated before `operator=` called, nothing more.), but the order of evaluation of the arguments is not specified. So there's no guarantee that `--linesArg` will be evaluated before  `new char[rows]`.

It's better to make the order clear and definite, to avoid the unspecified behavior and confusing.

```
--linesArg;
buffer[linesArg] = new char[rows];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is sequence point at ; so after assignment is complete the (so called side effect) decrement will have taken place for sure. Before that its unspecified.